# Fitting exponential trendline to data gnuplot

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit an exponential trendline to the following data which when graphed appears like the following:
[image]

Using the following code for the trendline:

```
\addplot+[raw gnuplot, red, mark=none, smooth] gnuplot {
    f(x)=a*exp(b*x+c)-0.06002;
    % let gnuplot fit, using column 1 and 2 of the data file
    % using the following initial guesses
    a=1000;
    b=-59571;
    c=0.005;
    set datafile separator ",";
     fit [0.005:] f(x) 'GE020.dat' using 1:2 via a,b,c;
         % Next, plot the function and specify plot range
         % The range should be approx. the same as the test.dat x range
     plot [x=0.00494:0.00515] f(x);
    set print "parameters.dat"; % Open a file to save the parameters into
};
\addlegendentry[]{\pgfplotstableread{parameters.dat}\parameters % Open the file Gnuplot wrote
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{0}\of\parameters \pgfmathsetmacro\paramA{\pgfplotsretval} % Get first element, save into \paramA
     $y=\pgfmathprintnumber{\paramA} \cdot x$  
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been filtered away)
```

And I expected the output:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: In addition we also don't have the `GE020.dat` so I don't see a chance how anybody should be able to help you except guessing, guessing, guessing.